# Is Linq2XSD Dead?

Tags: .net, xml, linq, xsd, linq-to-xsd

Does anyone have any updates on this since the [alpha 0.2](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?familyid=A45F58CD-FCFC-439E-B735-8182775560AF&displaylang=en)?

Comment: It's sad cuz i did like that project

Comment: It's still a very good project, and stable enough for anything I've needed it for so far. One of the smoothest libraries there is, actually - once you've installed visual studio integration per [README.txt](https://linqtoxsd.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/ReadMe.txt).

Comment: LinqToXsd has also been [released on Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/LinqToXsd). It's not an official package though - it doesn't modify your project files for you, plus it has path bugs in `LinqToXsd.targets`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Microsoft has now released LINQ to XSD as Open Source](http://www.westsoft.eu/blog/archive/2009/06/05/linq-to-xsd-is-now-open-source.aspx) so that the community might care for it.

Comment: unfortunately this project still doesn't have a download under the download tab, but if it fits your needs its not much work to download the source and compile it

Comment: http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/ <-- link to project on codeplex. The link in the answer is broken for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an old blog post from Scott Hanselman on this exact project, and the fact that it appeared dead to the outside world at one time.  Of course that was a year ago, so some things never change :)

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LINQToEverythingLINQToXSDAddsMoreLINQiness.aspx

UPDATE:

Found this forum thread, which seems to indicate the project is no longer active:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/2504e84a-1fe0-4eb3-a994-fdbc32121db0/

Comment: that @hanselman blog post is dead. he hasnt updated it in nearly two years

Comment: To a degree my entire answer is useful only for historical reference, as the project is now open sourced. See response above marked as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the
[Status of LINQ to XSD](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=384913)

More info you can find here
[linq-to-xsd](http://www.westsoft.eu/blog/archive/2009/05/07/linq-to-xsd.aspx)

I'm still hoping that this project will be picked-up for .net 4.0 and VS2010

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea, and is actually what I thought LINQ to XML would be until I looked in to it.

This is a semi-official blog from the Microsoft XML team:
http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/11/27/typed-xml-programmer-welcome-to-linq.aspx

The series of posts dried up sometime ago:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ralflammel/archive/2006/11/13/table-of-contents-for-typed-xml-programmer-series.aspx

Perhaps its been shelved for now.